# Dart DNS lookup TXT record

Tags: dart, dns

I am currently building an dart package and therefore I have to fetch the TXT record of a certain domain. My research did not bring up anything I can use.  Is there something compared to dnsjava in dart or is there another way to achieve that?

Regards

Comment: You can use https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/Socket-class.html or check https://pub.dartlang.org/ for packages with that functionality. Questions about external resources like packages or libraries are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I found an open issue at the official github repository : https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it will take even longer for this function to be implemented in the dart sdk, I have written a small helper class that can be used to query a record. It uses the google dns resolver api to fetch the records. I added this helper class to my helper class collection :

https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

Add the following line to your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.0.6
```

Since it uses the google api, it should also work with the flutter framework!